# Get lua state inside lua

Tags: lua

I would like to get the lua state from inside lua so I can pass it too an external program that cannot be hooked up using ffi or dll. I just need a pointer to it and the ability to share it(shared memory across program boundaries.

That or I can create a lua state in my program and then pass that so I would simply need to set the lua state to it inside lua(and it would have to work with shared memory).

I've thought about sharing data using json but ideally I would like to directly access objects.

Comment: "*I can pass it too an external program that cannot be hooked up using ffi or dll.*" Even if you could get the Lua state, the Lua state is a pointer to an object. The "external program" would have no access to the Lua program's process and thus cannot just access its memory.

Comment: @NicolBolas Which is why I said it has to be in shared memory. I can allocate a lua state in shared memory in my program and then pass it to lua and lua could use it if it can be told... but working the other way lua would have to allocate the state in shared memory for my program to access it precisely for the reasons you stated. It can be done, it is not rocket science... but lua may not directly support it.

Answer (score 1):

Lua is pretty good about avoiding heap allocation and global pointers to allocated memory. [`lua_newstate` takes](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_newstate) an [allocator function as a parameter.](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_Alloc) The provided function will be used to allocate/deallocate all memory associated with the `lua_State` object. Including the pointer returned by `lua_newstate`.

So hypothetically, you could provide an allocator function that allocates/deallocates interprocess shared memory. And then, you can just pass the `lua_State` to some other process and access it.

First, you clearly cannot do this "from inside lua"; that kind of low-level thing just ain't happening. You cannot access the `lua_State` object from within Lua. You must be in control of the `lua_State` creation process for that to be a possibility. So we're talking about C (equivalent) code here, not in-Lua code.

Now, you can expose a C function to Lua which returns a light userdata that just so happens to be the exact `lua_State*` in question. But Lua can't really do much with light userdata other than pass it to other C function APIs.

Second, while the Lua system provides a guarantee that it will only allocate memory through the allocator, the system does *not* provide a guarantee that what you're trying to do will work. It is entirely possible that the Lua implementation does use process global memory, so long as it does it in such a way that different threads can access that global memory without breaking threading guarantees.

Obviously, you can inspect the Lua implementation to see if it does anything of the kind.  But my point is that the guarantees are that each independent `lua_State` will be thread-isolated from each other and that each `lua_State` will only allocate memory through the given allocator. There is no guarantee that Lua's implementation doesn't have some global storage that it uses for some purpose.

So simply sharing the memory allocated by the Lua state may not be enough.

Also, even if this works, the two processes cannot access the same `lua_State` object at the same time, just like two threads in the same process cannot access the `lua_State` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The lua state is not designed to leave the program / thread it is executing in.

Doing a query on a running lua_state could result in a crash, because it is only notionally consistent when a lua call returns, or a C api function is called.  During execution, some un-locked modifications could cause uninitialized memory access, or ininite loops due to lists being inconsistent.

Comment: In my case the lua state won't change when my program is running... only threads could change it which I am not running any. I would only be using it to transfer data back and forth and so the data would be consistent since, effectively, everything would be single threaded.